# 401 Unauthrorized response while creating a Rest API instance?

Tags: rest, marklogic

I'm trying to send a **POST** request on http://xyz:8002/LATEST/rest-apis using Firefox's rest client. I have added two headers ***Content-Type: application/xml*** and ***Authorization:Basic*** which I selected using the dropdown UI. The body of the request is -

```
<rest-api xmlns="http://marklogic.com/rest-api">
  <name>Status Dashboard</name>
  <database>r75-xyz-v11</database>
  <port>8020</port>
</rest-api>
```

In response I'm getting a 401 Unauthoried.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <title>401 Unauthorized</title>
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>401 Unauthorized</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have Admin rights and I gave the same credential in the UI box that came after selecting authentication basic.

Comment: use a command line tool like Curl in debug mode. share the command and the results. once it is working, then re-create in your REST cleint

Comment: curl was my 1st option but that is restricted and I do not have admin rights of my system.

Comment: glad it is sorted. If you have access to query console, you can also use the HTTP client to do tests like this.

Answer (score 2):

Is port 8002 configured for BASIC or DIGEST (the default) authentication?

By the way, I don't think the name of the appserver can contain a space.

Comment: You are right. I changed the appserver authentication to DigestBasic from Digest but now I'm getting 400 Bad request. Still working on it.

Comment: Ohk! I finally got 201. You are right again the app server name cannot have spaces in between